# jquery auto-complete gem not working in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to use auto-complete in my application. But After installing autocomplete , it throws error

```
"couldn't find file 'autocomplete-rails' with type 'application/javascript' "
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Spree::Home#index
```

[image]

Please guide me how to use autocomplete in my application.

Comment: Can you show your `application.js` file?

Comment: post your application.js file

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your `Gemfile`

then run `bundle install`

Once check your `application.js` file and add below lines

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

That's it.

If still you are getting the same error add below `cdn` to your `application.html`

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.devbridge-autocomplete/1.2.27/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

That's it and Happy Coding...